# Failed to add i915 component master

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics, i915

I've installed "NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.57.run".It gives me this during reboot:

```
/dev/sda5:clean, 273157/1220608 files, 2413783/4882432 blocks
[8.012027] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: failed to add i915_bpo component master(-19)
```

Then it got stuck until i reinstall the nvidia driver again,in tty mode.
After reboot,it gave me the same error but didnt stuck.
I dont want to uninstall the driver because it may cause some more problems with CUDA and Tensorflow.

```
dmesg | grep i915
```

Gives me exact same error.

Intel 6600k,970gtx,Gigabyte Z170-HD3P-CF motherboard

Answer (score 0):

Try with going to BIOS

Advance -> Advance \ Systems Agent (SA) Configuration -> Configuration graphics > Multi-GPU Monitor

And changing this option